# Error when trying to use custom realm for Shiro

Tags: jsf-2, shiro

Using for BalusC tutorial for implementing shiro to a JSF app
http://balusc.blogspot.fi/2013/01/apache-shiro-is-it-ready-for-java-ee-6.html

Currently I am trying to add my own custom realm on top of the example, but I am obviously missing something.

I have the shiro.ini as follows (mainly copied from the given tutorial and probably all is not necessary):

```
[main]
user = com.example.filter.AjaxSessionFilter
mockRealm = com.example.realm.MockRealm
authc.loginUrl = /Login.xhtml
user.loginUrl = /Login.xhtml

[users]
admin = password

[urls]
/Login.xhtml = user
/* = user
securityManager.realms = $mockRealm
```

My MockRealm in short:

```
import org.apache.shiro.realm.AuthorizingRealm;

public class MockRealm extends AuthorizingRealm { /* Implement stuff */ }
```

I am running this on GlassFish v4.1. Everything worked so far correctly until I tried to add this custom realm. This results in the following error:

```
Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There is no filter with name '$mockRealm' to apply to chain [securityManager.realms] in the pool of available Filters.  Ensure a filter with that name/path has first been registered with the addFilter method(s).
```

I fail to find any information about this error, neither can I find any example how to implement the custom realm correctly.

Could any one point me to right direction? Thanks.

Comment: I think you might have an error in your web.xml

Comment: The web.xml is same as with the tutorial by BalusC, It complains about filter, but since I am not (supposedly?) adding a filter, I do not get it. If it really would be a filter, I would know to add it as a filter in web.xml.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about the dynamic 'filter creation' by shiro. This is defined in shiro.ini. Try moving your last line to the [main] section. That is where it belongs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this happens (annoyingly) often.
After a sleep I realized that the
`securityManager.realms = $mockRealm`
could be at wrong part of the *shiro.ini*.
Moved this under the `[main]` and it worked.
Sometimes you just have to forget things for a while to get a fresh look at them.

Comment: Sorry, not this time. It was in config, but in shiro.ini.

Comment: @Kukeltje Reviewed this to accept the answer, didn't notice that latter comment of yours. You were correct in that one. Besides, as you see, I added my answer 12 minutes before your comment. :)

Comment: No problem... Nothing to start arguing about. Just wondering how you can see your answer was 12 minutes before my comment above… (below the question)